# What is the Ismaili equivalent of zakah?

Tags: zakat, shia-ismaili

In Sunni Islam, there's a concept of *zakah* -- 2.5% (1/40) of your savings saved for a year need to be given to the poor in eight groups, which are outlined in *ayah az-zakah* (The Ayah of Zakah). This is well understood.

I know some people who are Ismailis. I have heard them talking about a similar concept, except that it is one eighth (12.5%), and apparently it also applies to cooked food and other things.

My question is, **what is this called and what is the "fiqh" of it?**

Answer (score 1):

**What is the Ismaili equivalent of zakah?**

The Ismaili equivalent of zakah is dasond. The amount of dasond is generally between 10% or 12.5% of one’s net income.

However, Ismailis don't consider dasond (zakah) as charity or alms. They interpret zakah as "**purification dues**". It is considered as a “purification due” that is given to the Imam ([Ismaili doctrine of Imamah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imamah_(Ismaili_doctrine))), for which the Imam bestows his prayers and blessings on them and purifies them (forgives their sins).

Fiqh of dasond (summarized below):

> Dasond must be given willingly, wholeheartedly, truthfully and with
>   trust in the Imam of the Time – only then will it bring worldly and
>   spiritual benefit to the murid (KIM, No. 1, September 1, 1885)
>
> The Imam of the Time is the one who distributes the dasond monies
>   appropriately (KIM, No. 1, September 1, 1885)
>
> Without giving dasond, one’s worship (‘ibadat) is not accepted (KIM,
>   No. 2, Bombay, September 8, 1885)
>
> Every murid has promised to give dasond to the Imam and those who do
>   will attain spiritual liberation (KIM, No. 2, Bombay, September 8,
>   1885)
>
> Those who have not given dasond, the right of the Imam, will be
>   accountable on the Day of Judgment (KIM, No. 21,, Manjevadi, January
>   2, 1894)
>
> One’s earnings and food are only permissible (halal) after giving
>   dasond (KIM, No. 24, Amdavad, December 2, 1896)
>
> Faith (iman) remains secure through giving dasond (KIM, No. 125,
>   Nairobi, October 6, 1905)
>
> The Imam accepts dasond from the murids and forgives their sins (KIM,
>   No. 125, Nairobi, October 6, 1905)
>
> Without giving dasond, all other deeds are meaningless and one will
>   have nothing in the hereafter (KIM, No. 155, September 22, 1899)

Answer (score -1):

There is no real fiqh in Ismailism. It is mostly based on whims of the imaam.

For example: Most Ismailis are told to marry within the community, but all of the imaams children marry outside. ( not one found a suitable spouse within the Ismaili community )

Dasond is really a "pay to pray" scheme. In this scheme the higher the dasond you give the more spiritual enlightenment you can get by attending a higher majalis or prayer.

All this money goes to aga khan ( not the poor ), which then aga khan claims to do "good" with his AKDN.

To read more go to
https://ismailitoislam.com/understanding-ismailism/

- an ex ismaili

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help] to learn more about how this site is supposed to work. And read [answer] to learn what kind of answers do we expect.